# Detecting an existing 2D shape on the canvas in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way in Three.js where one can detect if an existing **2D shape** is already drawn on the canvas - thus avoiding drawing another 2D shape in the region occupied by the first shape?

E.g. say, a triangle drawn as a 2D shape with its vertices (0,0), (10,0), (5,5). Now, if another triangle is to be drawn, is there a way to detect the area covered by the first triangle, so as not to draw the second triangle over it, or overlapping it?

Comment: Am not very sure how a 2D collision would work based on this post which is for 3D meshes. Will try looking it up. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, this is not an absolute duplicate. I delete my comment.

Comment: Not at all. Actually, that has given a hint that 2D collision detection could  probably one way this may be achieved. Looking that up.